# Website, API and iPhone App let users login via Facebook

Tags: php, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a Website (PHP), API (PHP) and a native iPhone app. I want users to login with their Facebook account so they can post reviews / upload photo's via the Website or iPhone app to our server/database. This will also save me time to create a complete user registration system.

I'm trying to figure out how to create a uniform architecture for this kind of a solution. I'm thinking about the following thing:

**Registration:**

- Create a database table containing my users (table will have these fields: id, facebook_uid, firstname, lastname)
- iPhone App login scenario: user logs in via Facebook; presses on allow to give  permission for my app; returns to App with access_token (which is stored on his phone). After that makes an call to my own API to register the user (if not registered yet in database) with these information: facebook_uid, firstname and lastname.
- Website login scenario: user login via Facebook; redirects to my configured return url and registers the user (if not yet in database) with these values facebook_uid, firstname and lastname

**Posting a product review**

- Iphone App: Make an call to my API with the following parameter input: review_text, facebook access_token. My API will then make server side the API call to facebook to get facebook_uid. When I have retrieved the facebook_uid I insert into to the database the review record for this facebook user. (Instead of sending the Facecbook access_token I could have sent directly also the facebook_uid value to my API. But I thought this may be less secure, because anyone could then insert review on behave of other user if they know their facebook_uid)
- Website: With help of the Facebook Connect PHP library FB login session is available so I can insert server side directly the review by reading the sessions facebook_uid.

Is this a correct and safe way of using Facebook as login for your own platforms? Or are there any other PHP modules/libraries I could use to simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has an existing api here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

The page also contains a tutorial on how to implement this

For iPhone specific facebook login please look here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso

Comment: I'm aware of the Facebook API and libraries (which I'm using in PHP application and iPhone app). The thing here is that I'm building my own API to expose my own entities/products stored in my database. My own API offers functionality like writing a review of product or uploading a product photo to our server. Therefore I need to authenticate the facebook user.

Comment: Oh I see. That shouldn't be an issue. The login api will log the user in. From there you should be able to pass username etc to your api. The Facebook api deals with logging in. That's what your question asked right?

Comment: Yes, so the main thing was is this a secure way to it; passing facebook ACCESS_TOKEN to my own API over HTTPS to add a new user to my users database table. And when posting a review or uploading a photo via my own API passing the ACCESS_TOKEN again so my own API can resolve itself which facebook_uid it is.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar scenario. Keeping the access_token on the phone seems like a good idea, then passing this via your API to verify the user on your own database seems like a good idea as well.

Wouldn't it be just as safe to encrypt the access_token and store it in your own database and check against that as opposed to constantly pinging the Facebook API i.e.:

1. Login via Facebook, get Facebook UID and access_token.
2. Store both the UID and/or access_token in your database encrypted via md5 / sha.
3. Each time your API makes a call, pass the access_token and check it against the one stored to verify the call?